# Using pjsip with android

Tags: android, java-native-interface, pjsip

I successfully installed and builded the `pjsip` library and `pjsua` for android, I ran `pjsua` on my device and it worked, however I'm still lost on how to use the methods of this library.

I already took a look on the `CSipSimple` app and I noticed that the `jni` folders of these 2 projects are very different.

Do I have to convert each .c file of this library in .java files with `SWIG`?
If anyone has an example about how to implement it in a very simple way (a SIP register procedure for instance) it would be helpful.

Comment: Would you please post the answer below

Comment: Hello, in fact you don't need to implement the whole thing and SWIG makes your life more complicated when you need some callback from native. 
Take a look on how jni works try to call a native function from java using the tutorial and start implementing a simple app in native code like this one but with jni functions http://www.pjsip.org/pjsip/docs/html/page_pjsip_sample_simple_pjsuaua_c.htm
which helps you understand how to use it.
Warning: the debug environment is a mess to set up, watch out the makefiles for jni and sometimes eclipse might be your ennemy.
Have fun.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer, but I prefer to have a discussion with you through Skype or so, is that possible?

Comment: Can you put some tutorial how you did it or share your src

Comment: I would love some more info on this, I am at the same place you where.  there seems to be no commands to call

Comment: Same here... more info is highly appreciated...

Comment: Hey can you give a basic android studio project for pjsip?

Comment: Its giving me error.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you would like to use the library.

The highest level API for pjsip is pjsua2 API, and there is already a java SWIG library build for you in the source code. You can just look at these examples.

http://www.pjsip.org/docs/book-latest/html/intro_pjsua2.html#building-python-and-java-swig-modules

However, if you don't need the sip signaling part, but just the media codecs and transportation part. You might have to design a JNI interfaces by yourself.
You write the programs in C/C++ and link the libpjsua.so in the Android.mk file.
for pjsua api C programming example:
http://www.pjsip.org/docs/latest/pjsip/docs/html/group__PJSUA__LIB__BASE.htm

for pjmedia example: see the testing codes under pjmedia/src/test