# PJSip : Making a call / Missing headers?

Tags: android, java-native-interface, pjsip

I have implemented the PJSIP framework in to my Android app using the sample app PJSUA which works via telnet.

How do I now generate, access header files/ functions to make call etc.  Do I have to modify the SWIG script to generate more files.

I only get the following so far

- Pjsua.java
- pjsuaAppCallBack.java
- PjsuaJNI.java

Looking at iOS code and CSIPSimple, there seems to be a lot more header files

**Update**
I looked at this post, it seems I may need to use jni?? and run the direct commands, any advice would be great

[Using pjsip with android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15817054/using-pjsip-with-android)

"Hello, in fact you don't need to implement the whole thing and SWIG makes your life more complicated when you need some callback from native. Take a look on how jni works try to call a native function from java using the tutorial and start implementing a simple app in native code like this one but with jni functions pjsip.org/pjsip/docs/html/… which helps you understand how to use it. Warning: the debug environment is a mess to set up, watch out the makefiles for jni and sometimes eclipse might be your ennemy. Have fun"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested in this, basically at the moment they (PJSIP) are still working on a nice Android implementation.  I contacted support and they helped me through making all the header files etc.

I recommend contacting them for anyone looking in to PJSIP